# Inequality involving primes

Tags: number-theory

> Suppose that $p,q$ and $r$ are primes such that $p>q>r$, and $kp+1$ divides $qr$ for some $k\neq 0$. Then $1+kp=qr$.

I really need help on this. Any hint how to establish this? Thank you.

Comment: Is this correctly copied? If indeed $1-kp=qr$, then $kp+1=2-qr$ which cannot possibly divide $qr$ (since $qr$ is at least $6$). So the only way for the entire claim to be true is if $kp+1\mid qr$ is in fact impossible.

Comment: Do you mean $1+kp=qr$?

Comment: Yah, I edited the question. It must be $1+kp=qr$.

Comment: Also include the possibility $1+kp=-qr$ please...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean $1+kp=rq$. And if $k$ is supposed to be a positive integer, this is obvious since the only other positive divisors $1,q,r$ of $qr$ are all less than $p$, and therefore less than $1+kp$. If you allow $k$ to be negative then there is a counterexample for $p=7,q=3,r=2,k=-1$.